# Replace Native DLL from Nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a Nuget package which is using an outdated patch version of a native library.

Is there a way to make my application use/install a newer DLL instead?

I tried replacing the DLL inside the `Runtimes/` folder, but it seems to always revert back to the nuget package dll whenever I build.

Comment: Use the full namespace of the library.  You can have more than one reference in a project to a library.  Each library will contain a namespace like System.Runtime.  If you have your own project you can call the library with MyNamespace.System.Runtime.

Comment: what does the namespace have to do what DLL i am using?
I have a Nuget Dependency which uses an outdated *native* DLL. I want to replace the outdated DLL with a newer one

Comment: Is it a 3rd party nuget or in-house? Is there a newer version of the nuget? Is it open source? If so, you could fork it or contribute the update?

Comment: The namespace is where the object is found.  It is like folders in a file system.  Each library is a path in the filesystem and each class is a file in the path.   You can have to files with same name in two different folders.  Normally c# will take the shortname of a class (without the namespace), but when you have two classes with same name you need to specify the full namespace.  The dll is a class library.

Comment: Me too, I am still wondering where you are going with the namespace @jdweng? I read this, so there is a 3rd party nuget that has a native lib as dependency. How would I as client of the nuget be able to make it use a new version of that dependency native lib by utilizing namespaces?

Comment: Only in your project? Add the dll to your project and set its "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always". Hopefully the order of thing s is fitting so it happens after copying the dll from the nuget folders.